# Como eliminar los elementos duplicados de una matriz c++

Tags: c++, array, vectores

al crear y duplicar la matriz me la escribe de la forma que quiero, mi pregunta es como puedo eliminar los elementos duplicados de la matriz1 debido a que necesito que únicamente me muestre los valores de la matriz sin mostrar los duplicado. Seria mas o menos de la siguiente forma.

Ingresar numero de filas: 3.

Ingresar numero de columnas: 4.

Arreglo Original:.

3 7 14 2.

6 2 3 15.

10 8 11 6.

Arreglo Resultante:
3.

7.

14.

2.

6.

15.

10.

8.

11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
  int f = 0;
  int c = 0;
  cout<<"Ingresar numero de filas: ";
  cin>>f;
  cout<<"Ingresar numero de columnas: ";
  cin>>c;
  int matriz[f][c];
  int matriz1[f][c];

  srand(time(0));
  for (int i = 0 ; i < f; i++ )
      for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++ )
         matriz[i][j] = 1 + rand()% 15;

  cout<< "Arreglo Original"<< endl;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < f; i++ ){
       for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++ ){
           cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" "; }
       cout<< endl;
}


cout<< "Arreglo resultante "<<endl;
for (int i = 0 ; i < f; i++ ){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++ ){
        matriz1[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
    cout<< matriz1[i][j]<<endl;}

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Al eliminarlos quieres que su lugar quedé ocupado por otro elemento o cómo esperas que se comporte? Por cierto, estás en C++. Recomiendo utilizar los headers `.h` en lugar de `c...`. Ejemplo: `time.h` y `ctime`.

Comment: solo que no aparezcan en la segunda lista

Comment: @Mateo es justamente al revés. Las cabeceras propias de C++ son las que **empiezan por c** y **no tienen extensión**

Comment: @eferion gracias por notarlo. Al revés entonces. A veces me confunde la existencia de 2 o hasta 3 versiones de algo. Cómo `string, string.h y cstring`.

Comment: @Mateo `string` es la cabecera propia de `c++` que proporciona la clase `std::string`. `string.h` son las funciones heredadas de C para trabajar con cadenas de caracteres `char*` y `cstring` es la cabecera anterior con algunas adaptaciones a C++ (las funciones se cargan en el namespace y poco más)

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que necesitas para realizar el ejercicio es, para cada número de la matriz, recorrer la matriz para buscar duplicados y, si no existen duplicados, sacar su número por la pantalla.

```
for (int f1=0; f1<f; f++)
{
    for (int c1=0; c1<c; c1++)
    {
        int repeticiones = 0;
        for (int f2=0; f2<f; f2++)
        {
            for (int c2=0; c2<c; c2++)
            {
                if (matriz[f1][c1] == matriz[f2][c2])
                    repeticiones++;
            }
        }

        if (repeticiones == 1)
            std::cout << matriz[f1][c1] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guarda los datos en un `std::set`:

```
set<int> sin_repetidos;

for (const auto &fila : matriz)
{
    for (const auto &valor : fila)
    {
        std::cout << valor << '\t';
        sin_repetidos.insert(valor);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLBbhMxFDyvv2IUBLtbIKECLpt0pQJBcCiViDg1FXIdb2TktRfbWwmqfEyOHPsN@bBge5OwREXcnj1v3sw8PdY0z5mkarndPhKKyXbBMRHaOsNpXZI/f7ecOW36P5a7/pNZtxC6JEQoh5oKleXkjiSjE8w4KNPK8m8U31sOScHkZt3a1letFWpJEm7d5he4ApfYrOsb4TTqzdqi4Z6yuddotBU3kg9xMiJJZEHRmtuGMg6vPSYkCdIVzvBi3NVsVzPdOkwmGHxUS8MtNVBtzY2GN14JSW2BQWgTCmWJ6j8MpmVbqyMSC/qjEabWO/90iXfTN1N8OH87/TybFuh24oz4eVVdX7Hrsc9N0e202Md57514wz5LUXTQxPPK8R6/iAOOOgKp3Gl/UXSnEmymVdqFww8wuqDxEQGWHjIMSbIb2xGz6ln0kbE8D1MrbZDR1md6EunFri8nSR@7pdI/iigRoKT7OMMpnsJQtchyPMbp6zDysNpzY/hSalwasRSKyrkaBNzfVcwNH/qr4Q13YqHtwUy4JIeHLd3tXfWbjr2FpiSucO@k6/BFOnfpOMJ96aHwt2tcFtvygK/I0YR0rgJx1Y8384dxmFHEcP8295dgcPmAtyBBEsNda1Q469V2@5K8Ir8B)</kbd>:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    /* Se aconseja que la cláusula using
    esté en el ámbito más pequeño posible. */
    using namespace std;

    int f = 0;
    int c = 0;
    cout << "Ingresar numero de filas: ";
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Ingresar numero de columnas: ";
    cin >> c;

    // Esto NO DEBE HACERSE: int matriz[f][c]; usa vector:
    using Fila = std::vector<int>;
    using Matriz = std::vector<Fila>;

    // Una matriz de 'f' filas y cada fila de 'c' columnas.
    Matriz matriz(f, Fila(c));

    for (auto &fila : matriz)
        for (auto &valor : fila)
            valor = 1 + rand() % 15;

    cout << "Arreglo Original\n";

    set<int> sin_repetidos;

    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
        {
            std::cout << valor << '\t';
            sin_repetidos.insert(valor);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << "Sin repetidos:\n";
    for (const auto &valor : sin_repetidos)
        cout << valor << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```